# Could not attach to pid : "15968"

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, pid

Getting error while debugging Notification Extension:  Failure Reason: tried to attach to process already being debugged

Could not attach to pid : "15968"
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErromDomain

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting device and pc will solve the problem. For me that worked good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).